# Difference between free monads and fixpoints of functors?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, free-monad, fixpoint-combinators

I was reading http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/06/from-zero-to-cooperative-threads-in-33.html where an abstract syntax tree is derived as the free monad of a functor representing a set of instructions. I noticed that the free monad [Free](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.4.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free%20Free) is not much different from the fixpoint operator on functors [Fix](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unification-fd/0.5.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Fixedpoint.html#t:Fix).

The article uses the monad operations and `do` syntax to build those ASTs (fixpoints) in a concise way. I'm wondering if that's the only benefit from the free monad instance? Are there any other interesting applications that it enables?

Comment: The main benefit of the monad instance is `do` notation and reuse of combinators from `Control.Monad` (like `replicateM_` and `forM_` in the examples).  A common trick is to build up the type using a free monad but then demand that the result has type `FreeT f m Void` so that it can be converted to the fixed point of a functor.

Comment: The `Monad` instance enriches `Fix` with two things--definite termination from `return` and natural "extension" from `(>>=)`. A regular `(Fix f)` cannot be guaranteed to have any (finite) values at all (i.e. `(Fix Identity)`), but `(Free f)` is always inhabited at least by `Pure`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez can you elaborate on the second part of your comment? What would be an example use case?

Comment: @DanielVelkov You use the Void return trick whenever you want to get the best of both worlds: i.e. use a free monad to assemble the data type and then use an F-algebra to interpret it.  The Void return value enforces that the free monad you build is isomorphic to the fixed point of the base functor when you are done.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Is there a library function which does the conversion? Does it make sense to port all the morphisms from Fix to Free?

Comment: The main advantage of porting morphisms from `Fix` to `Free` is if you want to use `do` notation or combinators from `Control.Monad`.  If you don't need those things and you can assemble `Fix` values by hand then there is no need to go through the `Free` intermediate.  Just think of `FreeT f m Void` as a convenient monadic way way to build up values of type `Fix` that is a bit more beginner friendly.

Comment: Fix has the advantage of being a `newtype` which might make it easier for the compiler to rip off layers, but I'm not sure in light of all the final/CPS encodings of `free` that are lying about.

Comment: @DanielVelkov Also you have `affix :: Functor f => Free f Void -> Fix f` where `affix (Free f) = Free (fmap affix f)`. You don't need the `Pure` case since `Pure (a :: Void)` is a contradiction—you can't have values of type `Void`.

Comment: @tel, you should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Once more time with feeling, then!

Answer (score 19):

(N.B. this combines a bit from both mine and @Gabriel's comments above.)

It's possible for every inhabitant of the `Fix`ed point of a `Functor` to be infinite, i.e. `let x = (Fix (Id x)) in x === (Fix (Id (Fix (Id ...))))` is the *only* inhabitant of `Fix Identity`. `Free` differs immediately from `Fix` in that it ensures there is at least one *finite* inhabitant of `Free f`. In fact, if `Fix f` has any infinite inhabitants then `Free f` has infinitely many finite inhabitants.

Another immediate side-effect of this unboundedness is that `Functor f => Fix f` isn't a `Functor` anymore. We'd need to implement `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`, but `Fix` has "filled all the holes" in `f a` that used to contain the `a`, so we no longer have any `a`s to apply our `fmap`'d function to.

This is important for creating `Monad`s because we'd like to implement `return :: a -> Free f a` and have, say, this law hold `fmap f . return = return . f`, but it doesn't even make sense in a `Functor f => Fix f`.

So how does `Free` "fix" these `Fix`ed point foibles? It "augments" our base functor with the `Pure` constructor. Thus, for all `Functor f`, `Pure :: a -> Free f a`. This is our guaranteed-to-be-finite inhabitant of the type. It also immediately gives us a well-behaved definition of `return`.

```
return = Pure
```

So you might think of this addition as taking out potentially infinite "tree" of nested `Functor`s created by `Fix` and mixing in some number of "living" buds, represented by `Pure`. We create new buds using `return` which might be interpreted as a promise to "return" to that bud later and add more computation. In fact, that's exactly what `flip (>>=) :: (a -> Free f b) -> (Free f a -> Free f b)` does. Given a "continuation" function `f :: a -> Free f b` which can be applied to types `a`, we recurse down our tree returning to each `Pure a` and replacing it with the continuation computed as `f a`. This lets us "grow" our tree.

---

Now, `Free` is clearly more general than `Fix`. To drive this home, it's possible to see any type `Functor f => Fix f` as a subtype of the corresponding `Free f a`! Simply choose `a ~ Void` where we have `data Void = Void Void` (i.e., a type that cannot be constructed, is the empty type, has no instances).

To make it more clear, we can break our `Fix`'d `Functor`s with `break :: Fix f -> Free f a` and then try to invert it with `affix :: Free f Void -> Fix f`.

```
break (Fix f) = Free (fmap break f) 
affix (Free f) = Fix (fmap affix f)
```

Note first that `affix` does not need to handle the `Pure x` case because in this case `x :: Void` and thus cannot *really* be there, so `Pure x` is absurd and we'll just ignore it.

Also note that `break`'s return type is a little subtle since the `a` type only appears in the return type, `Free f a`, such that it's completely inaccessible to any user of `break`. "Completely inaccessible" and "cannot be instantiated" give us the first hint that, despite the types, `affix` and `break` are inverses, but we can just prove it.

```
(break . affix) (Free f)
===                                     [definition of affix]
break (Fix (fmap affix f))
===                                     [definition of break]
Free (fmap break (fmap affix f))
===                                     [definition of (.)]
Free ( (fmap break . fmap affix) f )
===                                     [functor coherence laws]
Free (fmap (break . affix) f)
```

which should show (co-inductively, or just *intuitively*, perhaps) that `(break . affix)` is an identity. The other direction goes through in a completely identical fashion.

So, hopefully this shows that `Free f` is larger than `Fix f` for all `Functor f`.

---

So why ever use `Fix`? Well, sometimes you only want the properties of `Free f Void` due to some side effect of layering `f`s. In this case, calling it `Fix f` makes it more clear that we shouldn't try to `(>>=)` or `fmap` over the type. Furthermore, since `Fix` is just a `newtype` it might be easier for the compiler to "compile away" layers of `Fix` since it only plays a semantic role anyway.

---

- Note: we can more formally talk about how `Void` and `forall a. a` are isomorphic types in order to see more clearly how the types of `affix` and `break` are harmonious. For instance, we have `absurd :: Void -> a` as `absurd (Void v) = absurd v` and `unabsurd :: (forall a. a) -> Void` as `unabsurd a = a`. But these get a little silly.

Comment: If you define them correctly, i.e. `newtype Id a = Id a` and `newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))`, then after `let x = Fix (Id x)`, `x` is `undefined` (as expected: `fix id = ⊥`, because both `Fix` and `Id` (the constructors) are strict.

Answer (score 10):

There is a deep and 'simple' connection.

It's a consequence of [adjoint functor theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem), left adjoints preserve initial objects: `L 0 ≅ 0`.

Categorically, `Free f` is a functor from a category to its F-algebras (`Free f` is left adjoint to a forgetful functor going the other way 'round). Working in **Hask** our initial algebra is `Void`

```
Free f Void ≅ 0
```

and the initial algebra in the category of F-algebras is `Fix f`: `Free f Void ≅ Fix f`

```
import Data.Void
import Control.Monad.Free

free2fix :: Functor f => Free f Void -> Fix f
free2fix (Pure void) = absurd void
free2fix (Free body) = Fix (free2fix <$> body)

fixToFree :: Functor f => Fix f -> Free f Void
fixToFree (Fix body) = Free (fixToFree <$> body)
```

Similarly, right adjoints (`Cofree f`, a functor from **Hask** to the category of F-**co**algebras) preserves final objects: `R 1 ≅ 1`.

In **Hask** this is unit: `()` and the final object of F-**co**algebras is also `Fix f` (they coincide in **Hask**) so we get: `Cofree f () ≅ Fix f`

```
import Control.Comonad.Cofree

cofree2fix :: Functor f => Cofree f () -> Fix f
cofree2fix (() :< body) = Fix (cofree2fix <$> body)

fixToCofree :: Functor f => Fix f -> Cofree f ()
fixToCofree (Fix body) = () :< (fixToCofree <$> body)
```

---

Just look how similar the definitions are!

```
newtype Fix f 
  = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

`Fix f` is `Free f` with no variables.

```
data Free f a 
  = Pure a 
  | Free (f (Free f a))
```

`Fix f` is `Cofree f` with dummy values.

```
data Cofree f a 
  = a <: f (Cofree f a)
```