# How to define a function type of a non-recursive functions that has still a recursive type

Tags: haskell, types, recursive-type

Given is a Javascript function like

```javascript
const isNull = x => x === null ? [] : [isNull];
```

Such a function might be nonsense, which is not the question, though.

When I tried to express a Haskell-like type annotation, I failed. Likewise with attempting to implement a similar function in Haskell:

```hs
let isZero = \n -> if n == 0 then [] else [isZero] -- doesn't compile
```

Is there a term for this kind of functions that aren't recursive themselves, but recursive in their type? Can such functions be expressed only in dynamically typed languages?

Sorry if this is obvious - my Haskell knowledge (including strict type systems) is rather superficial.

Comment: But you add `n` twice as parameter?

Comment: And the reason why this does not compile is because the output type would be `Num a => [a -> [a -> [a -> [a -> ...]]]]` (infinite type recursion).

Answer (score 5):

You need to define an explicit recursive type for that.

```
newtype T = T (Int -> [T])

isZero :: T
isZero = T (\n -> if n == 0 then [] else [isZero])
```

The price to pay is the wrapping/unwrapping of the `T` constructor, but it is feasible.

If you want to emulate a Javascript-like untyped world (AKA unityped, or dynamically typed), you can even use

```
data Value
   = VInt Int
   | VList [Value]
   | VFun (Value -> Value)
   ...
```

(beware of a [known bug](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#bugs-in-ghc))

In principle, every Javascript value can be represented by the above huge sum type. For example, application becomes something like

```
jsApply (VFun f) v = f v
jsApply _        _ = error "Can not apply a non-function value"
```

Note how static type checks are turned into dynamic checks, in this way. Similarly, static type errors are turned into runtime errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, the type `T` is no longer particularly informative.

Comment: @ftor What kind of information do you want to preserve? What kind of type would you expect?

Comment: I just meant that with hiding the recursive type the type annotation is no longer particularly useful to conclude the space of possible computations from it - at least in this very case. You could have chosen a more meaningful name for the newtype, but still would exchange a type signature with a simple name.

Comment: @ftor I see. Below leftaroundabout provides a more informative type expression like `Fix (ListT ((->) Int))`. In the general case, we would need type-level functions, like `Fix (\T -> (Int -> [T]))` but these are not supported by Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

Chi showed how such an infinite type can be implemented: you need a newtype wrapper to “hide” the infinite recursion.

An intriguing alternative is to use a [fixpoint formulation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix). Recall that you could pseudo-define something recursive like your example as

```
isZero = fix $ \f n -> if n == 0 then [] else [f]
```

Likewise, the *type* can actually be expressed as a [fixpoint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.0.7/docs/Data-Fix.html#v:Fix) of the relevant functors, namely of the composition of `(Int ->)` and `[]` (which in transformer gestalt is [`ListT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-List.html#t:ListT)):

```
isZero :: Fix (ListT ((->) Int))
isZero = Fix . ListT $ \n -> if n==0 then [] else [isZero]
```

Also worth noting is that you probably don't really want `ListT` there. `MaybeT` would be more natural if you only ever have zero or one elements. Even more nicely though, you can use the fact that functor fixpoints are [closely related to the free monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307416/difference-between-free-monads-and-fixpoints-of-functors), which gives you exactly that [“possibly trivial” alternative case](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-3.4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free):

```
isZero' :: Free ((->) Int) ()
isZero' = wrap $ \n -> if n==0 then Pure () else isZero'
```

`Pure ()` is just `return ()` in the monad instance, so you can as well replace the `if` construct with the standard [`when`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when):

```
isZero' = wrap $ \n -> when (n/=0) isZero'
```

Comment: `fix` is indeed intriguing. This is a good opportunity for me to get a better idea of the concept. Thanks!